# SU to unpriviledged user starting in priviledged directory

Tags: security, su, cd-command

So here's the story. So, I usually work as root, and sometimes I switch to unprivileged users (for example, user1) to try out some things. I noticed something peculiar:
When I switch to user1 and the CWD is a directory under /root (drwx------), for example, /root/Desktop (drwxr-xr-x), I can list the directory, read files as long as their permissions allow me as user1, and I can cd back and forth to subdirectories of /root/Desktop, like /root/Desktop/dir1 (drwxr-xr-x). However, as soon as I cd to /, I can no longer cd to /root/Desktop or and subdirectories of /root (Permission denied), even though their permissions should allow me, as they did before. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

> even though their permissions should allow me, as they did before

.. is simply a bad assumption.

The selected user ***obviously*** and ***fortunately*** does not have access to the `/root` directory.

The reason it works at first is because the user doesn't try to go in the directory where it doesn't have permission.  The mentioned sub-directories do appear to have looser permissions which you should fix.